# Android question: How can I programmatically create a border around a textview (without using any XML)?

Tags: java, android, textview, border

I have just started Android programming. I come from Java background. In Java Swing, there is no XML config for GUI, everything is done programmatically. I want to do the same in Android. I don't want to use any XML for UI on Android.

So, my question is that how can I programmatically create a border around a textview (without using any XML)?

I searched for answers on Internet (stackoverflow, etc.) but they all use some XML, but I don't want to use any XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's always good to come up with your own [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help you learning, rather than just copy paste code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this.

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(0xFF00FF00); 
gd.setCornerRadius(5);
gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setBackground(gd);
```